# Является ли вводным слово "в принципе"?

Tags: пунктуация

Я(,)в принципе(,) стрелянный воробей в этом деле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого вводного слова я не видела ни в одном справочнике, но думаю, что в этом предложении оно играет роль именно вводного, так как его  можно заменить словами "по существу", "как полагаю". 
Думаю, что здесь произошла трансформация полного предложения во вводную конструкцию, ср.: Я, если это принципиально (если дело в принципе), стреляНый воробей в этом деле.
Однако не следует путать употребление слова "в принципе" в качестве вводного и обстоятельства "в принципе" в предложениях типа: "Я не согласен с тобой в принципе (т.е. совершенно)".